# Bulletproofing SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, html-parsing, simplexml, domdocument

Everyone knows that we should always use DOM techniques instead of regexes to extract content from HTML, but I get the feeling that I can never trust the SimpleXML extension or similar ones.

I'm coding a OpenID implementation right now, and I tried using SimpleXML to do the HTML discovery - but my very first test (with alixaxel.myopenid.com) yielded a lot of errors:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 27: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 11 and head in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: </head> in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 64: parser error : Entity 'copy' not defined in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: &copy; 2008 <a href="http://janrain.com/">JanRain, Inc.</a> in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 66: parser error : Entity 'trade' not defined in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: myOpenID&trade; and the myOpenID&trade; website are in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 66: parser error : Entity 'trade' not defined in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: myOpenID&trade; and the myOpenID&trade; website are in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 77: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 8 and html in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: </html> in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 78: parser error : Premature end of data in tag head line 3 in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 78: parser error : Premature end of data in tag html line 2 in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 6
```

I recall there was a way to make SimpleXML always parse a file, independently if the document contains errors or not - I can't remember the specific implementation though, but I think it involved using DOMDocument. What is the best way to make sure SimpleXML always parses any given document?

And please don't suggest using Tidy, I think the extension is slow and it's not available on many systems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can load the HTML with [DOM's loadHTML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) then import the result to SimpleXML.

IIRC, it will still choke on *some* stuff but it will accept pretty much anything that exists in the real world of broken websites.

```
$html = '<html><head><body><div>stuff & stuff</body></html>';

// disable PHP errors
$old = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// restore the old behaviour
libxml_use_internal_errors($old);

$sxe = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
die($sxe->asXML());
```

Comment: Uff! That's better... Is this solution *bulletproof*? Can I trust it to parse any document?

Comment: @Alix well likely not *any* document. If the HTML is too broken, then it's too broken. But for most broken HTML this should work. An alternative would be to use XmlReader. That's a pull parser which let's you define what to do on what element. There is also a number of config options for the underlying libxml extension which you can use to influence the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

you could always try a SAX parser... A bit more robust to errors.

May not be as efficient on large XML.