# simplexml_load_file how to get the value a specific set of keys

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

Hello so this is the php I have:

```
if (file_exists('movies.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('movies.xml');

print $xml->key['Movie'];  
}
```

here is what movies.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict><dict>
<key>2066</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ID</key><integer>111</integer>
            <key>Year</key><string>2011</string>
            <key>Movie</key><string>The beach</string>
<dict>
<key>2068</key>
                <dict>
            <key>ID</key><integer>112</integer>
            <key>Year</key><string>2012</string>
            <key>Movie</key><string>Titanic</string>
<dict>
```

I am trying to get `<key>Movie</key>` value 
in this case it will be : The beach and Titanic.
(I would like stored in an array if possible)

any suggestions what Im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some poorly formatted XML. `simplexml_load_file` is returning false.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

> Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the XML document, or FALSE on failure.

Comment: Im on that page and I cant figure this thing out. Also poor formatting ? the file is from the itunes store...not sure if they would have it poorly formatted

Comment: There's no `</dict>` tag. I tried loading up your sample chunk of xml into simplexml_load_string (after adding a root <document> tag) and got errors. `Premature end of data in tag dict line 7` `Premature end of data in tag dict line 3`

Comment: I added the top of xml. its a 15mb file I cant copy the whole deal... thats why I just copied a piece of it sorry

Comment: You might want to try something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312319/bulletproofing-simplexmlelement to pre-format before loading into simplexml.